# fatal: Authentication failed for GIT MAC mojave

Tags: git, macos

I am not able to clone the repository from GIT. I have full access to GIT(azure devops). I am able to login from browser. but if i am trying to clone the repo i am getting below error,

*fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://dev.azure.com/test/_git/testproject/*

Can anyone help on this?
I am trying to clone on MAC machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I followed below link and it worked.
https://mycyberuniverse.com/how-fix-fatal-authentication-failed-for-https-github-com.html

Trick was instead of my password i had to gave access token generated by GIT and it worked. In windows it is not necessary.